# Why is grep unable to match on string "-n" and "-e" in bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, gnu

Long story short, narrowed my problem down to a one-liner:

`for a in {a..z}; do echo "-$a" | grep "\-$a"; done`

This prints all letters *but* `-e` and `-n`.

Looks like Linux version, bash version, flags to grep (`-P`, `-E`) etc do not matter!
Tested environments:

1. GNU bash, version 3.2.57(2)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) **on** SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4
2. GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) **on** Cygwin (base-cygwin 3.8-1; cygwin32 2.10.0-1)
3. **rextester** (bash online compiler; GNU bash 4.3.46)

Why are not `-e` and `-n` printed?
*(Removing the dashes in the code also removes the problem)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is that `-e`, `-n` are valid `echo` options and `echo` is not printing them.

Moreover you should use `--` in `grep` to separate options and pattern. Suggest you to use `-F` option in grep as well for fixed string search.

You may use:

```
for a in {a..z}; do grep -F -- "-$a" <<< "-$a"; done
```

```
-a
-b
-c
-d
-e
-f
-g
-h
-i
-j
-k
-l
-m
-n
-o
-p
-q
-r
-s
-t
-u
-v
-w
-x
-y
-z
```

Note that you may also use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
for a in {a..z}; do printf -- '-%s\n' "$a" | grep -F -- "-$a"; done
```

Comment: plus 1 for suggesting printf over echo.